# where's the error? strange error trying to implement openpay in a codeigniter api

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a situaction that's driving me crazy, i'm trying to implement Openpay into an Codeigniter REST API, i have a controller that is a webhook it's already set and ready and everything, the thing is i'm trying to do a transaction in my database when the payment its succeed and it does everything less that i've try everything, first i was trying to call  a model and make the insert on a table but it just stoped at that line of code. long story short i'll show my actual code:
                $this->log('a');
                $this->log($this->uuid->v4());
                $this->log($uname);
                $this->log($y['amount']);

```
            $this->db->flush_cache();
            $this->db->set('uuid',      $this->uuid->v4()); 
            $this->db->set('uname',     $uname); 
            $this->db->set('type',      'FUND'); 
            $this->db->set('amount',    $y['amount']); 
            $this->db->set('currency',  'MXN'); 
            $this->db->set('details',   'Fund made through openpay'); 

            /*$payData = array(
                'uuid'      => $this->uuid->v4(),
                'uname'     => $uname,
                'type'      => 'FUND',
                'amount'    => $y['amount'],
                'currency'  => 'MXN',
                'details'   => 'Fund made through openpay'
                );*/

            if ($this->db->insert('tableName')) {
                $this->log( 'DAMMMMM SuccessWebhook|' . $msg );                 
            }else{
                $this->log( 'FAIL FAIL  FAIL|' . $msg );
            }

public function log($msg) {
    $data = array('message' => $msg);
    $this->db->insert('tableForLogs', $data);
}
```

... As you can see it's very simple what i'm trying to do i've done it a lot of times befor but i don't know what's happening, i use the log to try to find out whats happening with some sort of debuging with log's on the DB.
-I've cheked the parameters, they have the values.
-I've cheked the parameters on the DB i'm sending exactly what needed.
-I've tried to send the parameters one by one with set or in an array and send it like a parameter next to the insert .
-I've cheked the name of the table and attributes.
the program stops exactly at "$this->db->set('uuid',         $this->uuid->v4()); " i have debbug it with logs a lot of times.
please help me.

Comment: i also tried to make it on a query like this    $this->db->query("
     INSERT INTO v2_api_transaction (uuid, uname, type, amount, currency, details)
     VALUES (".$this->uuid->v4().", ".$uname.", 'FUND', ".$y['amount'].", 'MXN', 'Fund made through openpay');");

Answer (score 0):

At the end the problem was that i was trying to put a field that conflicts with a foreing key.I solve that and that was it. xD